# Mapstruct: from a list of OM to list of entity (parent/child relationship) and viceversa

Tags: java, mapstruct

I need to map a List into List in this following way (and viceversa)

One MyOM (the parent) can have a list of MyOM inside (the children). A child can't have children. A parent can have no children.

MyEntity has a field "parent" of type MyEntity.

How can I use Mapstruct in order to build these list of objects correctly?

thanks a lot

my classes

```
class MyOM {
    private String label;
    private Set<MyOM> children;
}


class MyEntity {
    private String label;
    private MyEntity parent;
}
```

json example of list of OM

```
[
    {
        "label": "parent",
        "children": [
            {
            "label": "child_1",
            "children": []
            },
            {
            "label": "child_2",
            "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "noParent_1",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "label": "noParent_2",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

The interface is:

```
@Mapper(config = ServiceMapperConfig.class)
public interface IMyObjectMapper {

    MyOM map(MyEntity entity);

    List<MyOM> mapEntities(List<MyEntity> entities);

    MyEntity map(MyOM om);

    List<MyEntity> mapOMs(List<MyOM> dtos);

}
```

Comment: how MyEntity and MyOM is related?

Comment: they are two independent classes

Comment: Can you share the MapStruct interface/class on which you are working? I want to see what you have tried, so I can be sure to share with you the best solution.